# Is there an issue with BulkWriteResult on mongodb 3.4.1

Tags: mongodb, mongo-go

### Steps:

1. Make the collection empty
2. Try to bulk write around 3k+(3237 exact) records (all having UpdateOne model) in mongodb using **go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.3.4**.

### Issue:

For **mongodb 3.4.1** it is returning me BulkWriteResult with only upserted count as 237 and 237 upserted ids, while in db all the documents are upserted(3237 records).

The same thing when I am trying to do connecting to atlas **mongodb 4.2.8** it is working fine.

```
var orderedWrite = false
res, err := m.client.Database("dbName").Collection("collectionName").BulkWrite(context.TODO(), models, &options.BulkWriteOptions{Ordered: &orderedWrite})
```

models contain 3237 records all having UpdateOne write model.
Checked the values for res is 237 for UpsertedCount and its respective upserted ids.

Comment: What happens if you try to BulkWrite less records? Is there a threshold that below it there is no problem?

Comment: I tried with 999 records and then 1001 records. With 999 I got the correct value as 999 upserted while with 1001 I got 1. It seems to be an issue while updating the bulkwriteresult when batches are processes.

Comment: Update to most recent 3.4 release.